# pyspeckit error : AttributeError: 'Quantity' object has no 'x_to_pix' member

Tags: python, data-fitting, spectrum, astropy

I am trying to fit continnum using the  pyspeckit package in python

```
spec=specutils.io.fits.read_fits_spectrum1d("nov11.fits",dispersion_unit='angstrom')
sp = pyspeckit.Spectrum.from_spectrum1d(spec)                     
sp.baseline(xmin=2200,xmax=3600,exclude=[2500,2800],subtract=False,highlight_fitregion=True,order=2).
```

I encounter the following error, while trying to define the baseline parameters:

> AttributeError: 'Quantity' object has no 'x_to_pix' member

where

> x_to_pix(xval, xval_units=None, equivalencies=None)
>   Given an X coordinate in SpectroscopicAxis’ units, return the corresponding pixel number

sp.unit returns ''

sp.header returns ''.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This would be more appropriate to post as an issue on the pyspeckit github (https://github.com/pyspeckit/pyspeckit) than here

Comment: I posted the issue for you.  Please continue the conversation here: https://github.com/pyspeckit/pyspeckit/issues/199